Maven Build Failing Due To Local .m2 update Error
Description:
I'm encountering an issue with Maven Clean Install in IntelliJ IDEA where it's failing, and I'm seeing an error in the Local Repository settings under IntelliJ's Preferences.
Problem Description:
Maven Clean Install Failure: When I run mvn clean install in my IntelliJ project, it fails with an error message that I'm finding difficult to troubleshoot. The error seems to be related to the build process, but I'm not sure where exactly the problem lies.
Error in Local Repository Settings: Additionally, when I navigate to IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repository Settings > Local Repository, I'm seeing an error or something unusual that suggests there might be a configuration issue related to the local repository.
enter image description here
What I've Tried:

Checking Maven Settings: I've reviewed my Maven settings in IntelliJ to ensure that they are correctly configured, including the Maven home directory and repository settings.
Cleaning IntelliJ Cache: I've tried cleaning the IntelliJ cache and restarting IntelliJ to see if that resolves the issue, but the problem persists.
Reviewing pom.xml: I've checked my pom.xml file for any inconsistencies or errors that might be causing the build failure, but everything seems to be in order.
Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue further. Specifically, I would appreciate any insights on:

Common causes of Maven Clean Install failures in IntelliJ IDEA.
Potential misconfigurations or errors in the Local Repository settings within IntelliJ.
Steps to diagnose and resolve Maven build issues within IntelliJ IDEA.
Environment Details:

IntelliJ IDEA version: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Community Edition)
Maven version: 3.9.4
Operating System: macOS M14.0

First it would be very helpful to post the error message... furthermore you should upgrade your enviroment (IntelliJ, Maven)...
